# Variable changes value unexpectedly

Tags: c++

I have a code supposed to store data in in a 2 block array.

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#define POSITION_DATA 1
#define X_AXIS 1
#define Y_AXIS 0

using namespace std;

typedef int dot_coordinates[POSITION_DATA];

void set_coordinates(dot_coordinates* dot,int x, int y);


int main()
{
dot_coordinates dot1,dot2,dot3,dot4;

set_coordinates(&dot1,0,0);
set_coordinates(&dot2,7,0);
set_coordinates(&dot3,0,7);
set_coordinates(&dot4,7,7);

printf("\np1 : x=%d y=%d\n",dot1[X_AXIS],dot1[Y_AXIS]);
printf("\np2 : x=%d y=%d\n",dot2[X_AXIS],dot2[Y_AXIS]);
printf("\np3 : x=%d y=%d\n",dot3[X_AXIS],dot3[Y_AXIS]);
printf("\np4 : x=%d y=%d\n",dot4[X_AXIS],dot4[Y_AXIS]);

    return 0;
}

void set_coordinates(dot_coordinates* dot,int x, int y)
{
*dot[X_AXIS] = x;
*dot[Y_AXIS] = y;
}
```

The console result is the following :

p1 : x=0 y=7

p2 : x=7 y=0

p3 : x=0 y=7

p4 : x=7 y=7

shouldn't y=7 be y=0 for p1 ?

Now here is what happens when I replace the lines

```
set_coordinates(&dot1,0,0);
set_coordinates(&dot2,7,0);
set_coordinates(&dot3,0,7);
set_coordinates(&dot4,7,7);
```

with (the rest of the code is the same)

```
set_coordinates(&dot2,7,0);
set_coordinates(&dot3,0,7);
set_coordinates(&dot4,7,7);
set_coordinates(&dot1,0,0);
```

the result here is :

p1 : x=0 y=0

p2 : x=0 y=0

p3 : x=0 y=7

p4 : x=7 y=7

I have been trying to understand why this is happening but couldn't figure out why p1[X_AXIS] is copying p2[Y_AXIS].
Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: `#define POSITION_DATA 1`...you defined your dots as arrays of size 1 and then tried to write to (and read from) the second element. Undefined behavior results.

Comment: If that wasn't clear, he means you need to set POSITION_DATA to 2. An array of size one has one element [0], an array of size 2 has two elements [0], and [1].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined the type 'dot_coordinates' as an array of length 1 (via the POSITION_DATA macro). Then, in your set_coordinates function, you index into its second element. This is undefined behavior, and in this particular circumstance, you are overwriting variables stored in adjacent stack space.

Comment: Oh snap forgot about that... I was so sure That I had [0] and [1] at my disposal.. thanks man !

Comment: No problem - every C programmer experiences this hell once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array

```
int myArray[1];
```

then the size of the array will be 1, not 2. The indexes use zero-counting, but not the sizes.

Your program is exhibiting 'undefined behavior' as you are reading and writing outside the bounds of the array.